# OpenJDK Panama Vector API jdk.incubator.vector not giving improved results for Vector dot product

Tags: java, vectorization, dot-product, project-panama

I am testing [OpenJDK Panama Vector API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/338) jdk.incubator.vector and I performed tests on amazon c5.4xlarge instance. But in every case simple unrolled vector dot product is out performing the Vector API code.

*My Question* is :
Why am I not able to get the performance boost as shown in [Richard Startin's blog](https://richardstartin.github.io/posts/vector-api-dot-product). The same performance improvement is also discussed in [this conference meetup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YA9wfTrBr_4) by Intel people. What is missing?

JMH benchmark test results :

```
Benchmark                                              (size)   Mode  Cnt      Score    Error  Units

FloatVector256DotProduct.unrolled                       1048576  thrpt   25   2440.726 ? 21.372  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vanilla                        1048576  thrpt   25    807.721 ?  0.084  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vector                         1048576  thrpt   25    909.977 ?  6.542  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorUnrolled                 1048576  thrpt   25    887.422 ?  5.557  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma                      1048576  thrpt   25    916.955 ?  4.652  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled              1048576  thrpt   25    877.569 ?  1.451  ops/s

JavaDocExample.simpleMultiply                           1048576  thrpt   25  2096.782 ?  6.778  ops/s
JavaDocExample.simpleMultiplyUnrolled                   1048576  thrpt   25  1627.320 ?  6.824  ops/s
JavaDocExample.vectorMultiply                           1048576  thrpt   25  2102.654 ? 11.637  ops/s
```

AWS instance type : `c5.4xlarge`

CPU details :

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             3404.362
BogoMIPS:            5999.99
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke
```

**Code snippets.** Please see complete code in [this github repo](https://github.com/nitirajrathore/java-vectorization)

JavaDocExample : This is shared in the java doc of vectorIntrinsic branch of OpenJDK.

```
    @Benchmark
    public void simpleMultiplyUnrolled() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
            c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
            c[i + 1] = a[i + 1] * b[i + 1];
            c[i + 2] = a[i + 2] * b[i + 2];
            c[i + 3] = a[i + 3] * b[i + 3];
            c[i + 4] = a[i + 4] * b[i + 4];
            c[i + 5] = a[i + 5] * b[i + 5];
            c[i + 6] = a[i + 6] * b[i + 6];
            c[i + 7] = a[i + 7] * b[i + 7];
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void simpleMultiply() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void vectorMultiply() {
        int i = 0;
        // It is assumed array arguments are of the same size
        for (; i < SPECIES.loopBound(a.length); i += SPECIES.length()) {
            FloatVector va = FloatVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a, i);
            FloatVector vb = FloatVector.fromArray(SPECIES, b, i);
            FloatVector vc = va.mul(vb);
            vc.intoArray(c, i);
        }

        for (; i < a.length; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
        }
    }
```

FloatVector256DotProduct : this code is shamelessly copied from [Richard Startin's blog](https://richardstartin.github.io/posts/vector-api-dot-product). Thanks Richard for insightful blogs.

```
  @Benchmark
  public float vectorfma() {
    var sum = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += F256.length()) {
      var l = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i);
      var r = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i);
      sum = l.fma(r, sum);
    }
    return sum.reduceLanes(ADD);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public float vectorfmaUnrolled() {
    var sum1 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum2 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum3 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum4 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    int width = F256.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += width * 4) {
      sum1 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i).fma(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i), sum1);
      sum2 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width).fma(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width), sum2);
      sum3 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width * 2).fma(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width * 2), sum3);
      sum4 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width * 3).fma(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width * 3), sum4);
    }
    return sum1.add(sum2).add(sum3).add(sum4).reduceLanes(ADD);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public float vector() {
    var sum = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += F256.length()) {
      var l = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i);
      var r = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i);
      sum = l.mul(r).add(sum);
    }
    return sum.reduceLanes(ADD);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public float vectorUnrolled() {
    var sum1 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum2 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum3 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    var sum4 = FloatVector.zero(F256);
    int width = F256.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += width * 4) {
      sum1 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i).mul(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i)).add(sum1);
      sum2 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width).mul(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width)).add(sum2);
      sum3 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width * 2).mul(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width * 2)).add(sum3);
      sum4 = FloatVector.fromArray(F256, left, i + width * 3).mul(FloatVector.fromArray(F256, right, i + width * 3)).add(sum4);
    }
    return sum1.add(sum2).add(sum3).add(sum4).reduceLanes(ADD);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public float unrolled() {
    float s0 = 0f;
    float s1 = 0f;
    float s2 = 0f;
    float s3 = 0f;
    float s4 = 0f;
    float s5 = 0f;
    float s6 = 0f;
    float s7 = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
      s0 = Math.fma(left[i + 0],  right[i + 0], s0);
      s1 = Math.fma(left[i + 1],  right[i + 1], s1);
      s2 = Math.fma(left[i + 2],  right[i + 2], s2);
      s3 = Math.fma(left[i + 3],  right[i + 3], s3);
      s4 = Math.fma(left[i + 4],  right[i + 4], s4);
      s5 = Math.fma(left[i + 5],  right[i + 5], s5);
      s6 = Math.fma(left[i + 6],  right[i + 6], s6);
      s7 = Math.fma(left[i + 7],  right[i + 7], s7);
    }
    return s0 + s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public float vanilla() {
    float sum = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      sum = Math.fma(left[i], right[i], sum);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Process followed to compile and use the OpenJDK Panama dev vectorIntrinsic branch as showed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973158/cant-use-jdk-incubator-vector-classes-in-biginteger)

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/panama/dev/
cd dev/
hg checkout vectorIntrinsics
hg branch vectorIntrinsics
bash configure
make images
```

Things I checked why it should have worked.

1. lscpu shows all sorts of avx flags.
2. I chose HVM AMI which should support AVX instructions sets. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ says : † AVX, AVX2, and Enhanced Networking are only available on instances launched with HVM AMIs.
3. I can compile vector code which means I am using appropriate branch of OpenJDK. I ran my code with --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector VM parameter.
    I also added some other VM params like state in [this intel blog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vector-api-developer-program-for-java) : -XX:TypeProfileLevel=121
4. I checked the compiled assembly code it does contain vmulps instructions. Although it was difficult to find them as I am calling methods in vector api code and multiplication is happening at some other inside the called mul/fma method.
5. I have done lot more testing with different SIZE like 64, 128, 256, 512 and also using the ``FloatVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED``. In all cases vector api code is significantly slower then the simple multiplication code with unrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post which was answered in the by @iwanowww here: https://gist.github.com/iwanowww/221df8893fbaa4b6b0904e3036221b1d . In short, this was a regression issue that was fixed since then, details below.

**TL;DR it is fixed now**

> (1) The regression in FloatVector256DotProduct.vector* with latest vectorIntrinsics branch is caused by a bug in vector operations intrinsification:

```
   2675   92    b        net.codingdemon.vectorization.FloatVector256DotProduct::vector (75 bytes)
   ...
                            @ 3   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::zero (35 bytes)   force inline by annotation
                              @ 6   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector$FloatSpecies::vectorType (5 bytes)   accessor
                              @ 13   jdk.incubator.vector.AbstractSpecies::length (5 bytes)   accessor
                              @ 19   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::toBits (6 bytes)   force inline by annotation
                                @ 1   java.lang.Float::floatToIntBits (15 bytes)   (intrinsic)
                              @ 23   java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder::linkToTargetMethod (8 bytes)   force inline by annotation
                                @ 4   java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x0000000800b8c040::invoke (8 bytes)   force inline by annotation
                              @ 28   jdk.internal.vm.vector.VectorSupport::broadcastCoerced (35 bytes)   failed to inline (intrinsic)
```

> The following patch fixes the bug:

```
diff --git a/src/hotspot/share/opto/vectorIntrinsics.cpp b/src/hotspot/share/opto/vectorIntrinsics.cpp
--- a/src/hotspot/share/opto/vectorIntrinsics.cpp
+++ b/src/hotspot/share/opto/vectorIntrinsics.cpp
@@ -476,7 +476,7 @@

   // TODO When mask usage is supported, VecMaskNotUsed needs to be VecMaskUseLoad.
   if (!arch_supports_vector(VectorNode::replicate_opcode(elem_bt), num_elem, elem_bt,
-                            is_vector_mask(vbox_klass) ? VecMaskUseStore : VecMaskNotUsed), true /*has_scalar_args*/) {
+                            (is_vector_mask(vbox_klass) ? VecMaskUseStore : VecMaskNotUsed), true /*has_scalar_args*/)) {
     if (C->print_intrinsics()) {
       tty->print_cr("  ** not supported: arity=0 op=broadcast vlen=%d etype=%s ismask=%d",
                     num_elem, type2name(elem_bt),
```

> BEFORE:

```
Benchmark                                    (size)   Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
FloatVector256DotProduct.vanilla            1048576  thrpt    5   679.280 ±  13.731  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.unrolled           1048576  thrpt    5  2319.770 ± 123.943  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vector             1048576  thrpt    5   803.740 ±  42.596  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorUnrolled     1048576  thrpt    5   797.153 ±  49.129  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma          1048576  thrpt    5   828.172 ±  16.936  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled  1048576  thrpt    5   798.037 ±  85.566  ops/s
JavaDocExample.simpleMultiply               1048576  thrpt    5  1888.662 ±  55.922  ops/s
JavaDocExample.simpleMultiplyUnrolled       1048576  thrpt    5  1486.322 ±  93.864  ops/s
JavaDocExample.vectorMultiply               1048576  thrpt    5  1525.046 ± 110.700  ops/s
```

> AFTER:

```
Benchmark                                    (size)   Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
FloatVector256DotProduct.vanilla            1048576  thrpt    5   666.581 ±   8.727  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.unrolled           1048576  thrpt    5  2416.695 ± 106.223  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vector             1048576  thrpt    5  3776.422 ± 117.357  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorUnrolled     1048576  thrpt    5  3734.246 ± 122.463  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma          1048576  thrpt    5  3804.485 ±  44.797  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled  1048576  thrpt    5  1158.018 ±  15.955  ops/s
JavaDocExample.simpleMultiply               1048576  thrpt    5  1914.794 ±  51.329  ops/s
JavaDocExample.simpleMultiplyUnrolled       1048576  thrpt    5  1405.345 ±  52.025  ops/s
JavaDocExample.vectorMultiply               1048576  thrpt    5  1832.133 ±  56.256  ops/s
```

> (2) The regression in vectorfmaUnrolled (compared to vectorfma) is caused by well-known inlining issues which break vector box elimination:

```
Benchmark                                    (size)   Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma          1048576  thrpt    5  3804.485 ±  44.797  ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled  1048576  thrpt    5  1158.018 ±  15.955  ops/s

19727   95    b        net.codingdemon.vectorization.FloatVector256DotProduct::vectorfmaUnrolled (228 bytes)
    ...
    @ 209   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::add (9 bytes)   force inline by annotation
      @ 5   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::lanewise (0 bytes)   virtual call
    @ 213   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::add (9 bytes)   force inline by annotation
      @ 5   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::lanewise (0 bytes)   virtual call
    @ 218   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::add (9 bytes)   force inline by annotation
      @ 5   jdk.incubator.vector.FloatVector::lanewise (0 bytes)   virtual call
    ...

Benchmark                                                                     (size)   Mode  Cnt        Score        Error   Units
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma                                           1048576  thrpt    5     3938.922 ±     97.041   ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma:·gc.alloc.rate.norm                       1048576  thrpt    5        0.111 ±      0.003    B/op

FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled                                   1048576  thrpt    5     2052.549 ±     68.859   ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               1048576  thrpt    5  1573537.127 ±     22.886    B/op
```

> Until the inlining is fixed, as a workaround, a warm-up phase with smaller data input can help:

```
Benchmark                                                       (size)   Mode  Cnt         Score        Error   Units
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma                                 128  thrpt    5  54838734.769 ± 161477.746   ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfma:·gc.alloc.rate.norm             128  thrpt    5        ≈ 10⁻⁵                 B/op

FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled                         128  thrpt    5  68993637.658 ± 359974.720   ops/s
FloatVector256DotProduct.vectorfmaUnrolled:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     128  thrpt    5        ≈ 10⁻⁵                 B/op
```